# Service Reference could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, service-reference

I've created new website ( not web project ),
In solution explorer right click on project and clicked **Add Service Reference**

then I've add a web service provider address, a new folder named **App_WebReferences** created. It contains ServiceReference1 folder in which there are three files(two .svcinfo and one .wsdl).

Now I use this code as my provider guided:

```
var srv = new ServiceReference1.PaymentIFBindingSoapClient();
double result = srv.verifyTransaction(refNum, "10004738");
```

there is no error in compilation and running in localhost.
BUT
when I upload my website files to my ftp on the server..**I get this error message**:

```
*Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 
**Compiler Error Message:** CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ServiceReference1'     could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Source Error:

Line 69:             ///WebService Instance
Line 70:             //
Line 71:             var srv = new ServiceReference1.PaymentIFBindingSoapClient();
Line 72:             
Line 73:             double result = srv.verifyTransaction(refNum, "10004738");

Source File: d:\domains\olomrayaneh.net\wwwroot\ebook\check_payment.aspx.cs    Line: 71 

Show Detailed Compiler Output:
Show Complete Compilation Source:

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3643; ASP.NET     Version:2.0.50727.3634*
```

I've stuck in this problem. 
Whats the problem!?
How should I solve it?

I should say that I tried to add this line:

```
using ServiceReference1;
```

then the error message line changes to this line with the same message !

and again no error message in localhost running!

my website is build in .Net Framework 3.5

web.config -- after adding server reference, these lines added to web.config file:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
                <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="PaymentIFBindingSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                 openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"     sendTimeout="00:01:00"
     allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"     hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
     maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
     useDefaultWebProxy="true">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
     <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
       realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
     </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="PaymentIFBindingSoap1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
     openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
     allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"     hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
     maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
     useDefaultWebProxy="true">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
     <security mode="None">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
       realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
     </security>
    </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
        <client>
   <endpoint     address="https://acquirer.samanepay.com:2789/payments/referencepayment.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PaymentIFBindingSoap"
    contract="ServiceReference1.PaymentIFBindingSoap" name="PaymentIFBindingSoap" />
  </client>
        </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks friends.
I've solved it.

the problem was that I was copied all data to a subfolder under the wwwroot folder,

But I should copy the App_WebReference folder to the root of wwwroot folder !

Comment: It should also work in a subfolder. The only thing you have to do is to create an application on the subfolder: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Normally all service references are stored in the web.config file of the project und this file will normaly not deployed. Just check that your server web.config file contains also a reference to your service, if not add it from your local file.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
I've added web.config changes to my question.
please check it. should I do anything more ?

Comment: Just compare your web.config and the server web.config, but it looks like you got all settings. Does it work?

Comment: I've uploaded my own web.config to server. but the problem is on !
terrible !! no solution after 2 days searching!
thanks again.